# validate a textbox with default value

Tags: angular, html, mean-stack

I have a textbox as following:

```html
  <div form="form-group">
    <label for="Title"> <h3>Title:</h3>  </label>
    <div [ngClass]="{
    'has-errors': (dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.errors && dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.dirty ),

    'has-success': (!dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.errors )
    }">
      <input type="text" name ="Title" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Title"
             value="{{theDP.title}}" formControlName="Title">
      <!--Validations-->
      <ul class="help-block">
        <li *ngIf="(dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.errors?.required && dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.dirty)
                   ">
          This field is required</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The textbox is filled by the data I have read from DB in my ngOnInit() function.
Apparently, the validator dose not recognize that it has value, so it ask me to fill it. How should I modify the validoator to realize the value? I have used the following :

```
'has-success': (!dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.errors || dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.hasValue )
```

but doesnt seems to work. 
Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace Value with ngModel

```html
<div form="form-group">
    <label for="Title"> <h3>Title:</h3>  </label>
    <div [ngClass]="{
    'has-errors': (dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.errors && dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.dirty ),

    'has-success': (!dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.errors )
    }">
      <input type="text" name ="Title" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Title"
             ngModel="theDP.title" formControlName="Title">
      <!--Validations-->
      <ul class="help-block">
        <li *ngIf="(dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.errors?.required && dataProcessingEditForm.controls.Title.dirty)
                   ">
          This field is required</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it give me this error:  ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'has-errors: false'. Current value: 'has-errors: null'.

Comment: @user3075338  that give me the same erro. plus the textbox value became: theDP.title

Comment: @user3075338 did you replace value property with ngModel

Comment: @user3075338‌ check snippet.. it's not only showing the place holder.

Comment: @user3075338‌ not sure if i get what you mean